# PHP wont send data to mysql!? (undefined variable error)

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3

I have some data which is received from adobe flash AS3, the PHP file receives it, but I cant seem to send the data to mySQL...

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['userFirstName'])){ $userFirstName = $_POST['userFirstName']; }
if(isset($_POST['userLastName'])){ $userLastName = $_POST['userLastName']; }
if(isset($_POST['userEmail'])){ $userEmail = $_POST['userEmail']; }
if(isset($_POST['userNumber'])){ $userNumber = $_POST['userNumber']; }
if(isset($_POST['userMsg'])){ $userMsg = $_POST['userMsg']; }

$username="******";
$password="*******";
$database="b-elite-fitness";

mysql_connect("localhost","$username","$password") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$database") or die (mysql_error());

mysql_query("INSERT INTO formdp 
(ID ,firstname, lastname, email, number, message) 
VALUES('','$userFirstName[firstname]','$userLastName[lastname]','$userEmail[email]','$userNumber[number]','$userMsg[message]')")
or die (mysql_error());
echo "foo=bar&checking=ok";
mysql_close();
?>
```

I get this error for the php file...

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: userFirstName in C:\wamp\www\NewtestForm\form.php on line 18 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  
0.0094  253176  {main}( )   ..\form.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: userLastName in C:\wamp\www\NewtestForm\form.php on line 18 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  
0.0094  253176  {main}( )   ..\form.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: userEmail in C:\wamp\www\NewtestForm\form.php on line 18 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  
0.0094  253176  {main}( )   ..\form.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: userNumber in C:\wamp\www\NewtestForm\form.php on line 18 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  
0.0094  253176  {main}( )   ..\form.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: userMsg in C:\wamp\www\NewtestForm\form.php on line 18 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  
0.0094  253176  {main}( )   ..\form.php:0
```

Can anyone help me out I've been going at the problem for the past few days...

I'm new to PHP so could do with explanations as well...

EDIT UPDATE.... I changed the coding, however still get the same errors... here is my new coding....

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['userFirstName'])){ $userFirstName = $_POST['userFirstName']; }
if(isset($_POST['userLastName'])){ $userLastName = $_POST['userLastName']; }
if(isset($_POST['userEmail'])){ $userEmail = $_POST['userEmail']; }
if(isset($_POST['userNumber'])){ $userNumber = $_POST['userNumber']; }
if(isset($_POST['userMsg'])){ $userMsg = $_POST['userMsg']; }

$username="root";
$password="dp10aap";
$database="b-elite-fitness";

mysql_connect("localhost","$username","$password") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$database") or die (mysql_error());

mysql_query("INSERT INTO formdp 
    (id ,firstname, lastname, email, number, message) 
    VALUES('NULL','$userFirstName','$userLastName','$userEmail','$userNumber','$userMsg')") 
or die (mysql_error());
mysql_close();
?>
```

and here are my errors...

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: userFirstName in C:\wamp\www\NewtestForm\form.php on line 18
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0112  252456  {main}( )   ..\form.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: userLastName in C:\wamp\www\NewtestForm\form.php on line 18
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0112  252456  {main}( )   ..\form.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: userEmail in C:\wamp\www\NewtestForm\form.php on line 18
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0112  252456  {main}( )   ..\form.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: userNumber in C:\wamp\www\NewtestForm\form.php on line 18
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0112  252456  {main}( )   ..\form.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: userMsg in C:\wamp\www\NewtestForm\form.php on line 18
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0112  252456  {main}( )   ..\form.php:0

Comment: If these variables are undefined, your initial `isset` calls are returning `false`, so in fact your PHP is not receiving the data you are POSTing. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: fyi `mysql` is deprecated, and this code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  you should be using placeholders with `mysqli` or PDO

Comment: use `NULL` instead of `''` for your ID field. Presuming you have set the ID field to an auto incrementing integer?

Comment: @fuzic Could you help me identify where the problem may lay... if i show you my AS3 coding as well... as i initily thought that the error was between AS3 and PHP and not PHP to MYSQL...?

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect: `$userFirstName[firstname]`

I assume that `$_POST['userFirstName']` is a string, in which case you would only use `$userFirstName` to access the variable. If it is an array, you are missing quotes to access the array index: `$userFirstName['firstname']`.

The same goes for the rest of your variables.

Comment: I get the following error now.... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING

Answer (score 0):

You made your own variables associative arrays by adding `['identifier']` to them. That makes them different from the initial ones, and then you try to use them as if you have put some value in them, that's why you get the errors. Just use them the way they are. Like this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO formdp (ID ,firstname, lastname, email, number, message) 
VALUES('','$userFirstName','$userLastName','$userEmail','$userNumber','$userMsg')")
or die (mysql_error());
```

Remember to sanitize your user's input and also note that `PHP`'s `mysql` extenstion is deprecated. Consider `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: I changed it like you suggested, i get a final error of Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file... on the last line

Comment: I still get the same errors... after checking my coding i missed out " i added it and get the same error as i did before even after changing the coding as you suggested... @chibuzo

Comment: @user2080616 edit your question and add the code for your form, let's start from there.

Comment: there you go I've changed the coding as you suggested, however i get the same errors...  any ides ?

Comment: Your $_POST variables are most likely not set.

Answer (score 0):

Your php code is not receiving your POSt data. Have you done a vardump on $_POSt to see what exactly it is holding?